# Sumar cada key de un un objeto en un array de arrays, manteniendo el formato del array

Tags: javascript

tengo los siguientes datos

```
[[{aceptacion: 1, rechazo: 2},
 {aceptacion: 0, rechazo: 1}],
[{aceptacion: 2, rechazo: 2},
 {aceptacion: 0, rechazo: 7}],
[{aceptacion: 0, rechazo: 2},
 {aceptacion: 0, rechazo: 3}]]
```

y necesito como respuesta lo siguiente:

```
[{aceptacion: 3, rechazo: 6},
 {aceptacion: 0, rechazo: 11}]
```

pero nose como sumar para llegar a ese resultado.

**en teoria seria:**

> sumar las aceptaciones del primer Objeto de cada arreglo, 1+2+0=3
>
> sumar las aceptaciones del segundo Objeto de cada arreglo, 0+0+0=0
>
> **.......hasta el elemento N**
>
> y lo mismo con los rechazos

mi intento es:

```js
let arreglo = [
    [{
        aceptacion: 1,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 1
      }
    ],
    [{
        aceptacion: 2,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 7
      }
    ],
    [{
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 3
      }
    ];
    let suma
    arreglo.forEach(function(d) {
      d.[0]
    })
```

Comment: En base  a que condiciones se debe determinar la respuesta, agrega eso en tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Comment: Eso es un array de arrays? O es que esta mal escrito el codigo? Comienzas con `let arreglo = [` pero nunca lo cierras.

Comment: si es un array de arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posibilidad es la siguiente:

```js
let arreglo = 
[
    [{
        aceptacion: 1,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 1
      }
    ],
    [{
        aceptacion: 2,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 7
      }
    ],
    [{
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 3
      }
    ]
];

let resultado = arreglo[0]
for (var i = arreglo.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { //Excluyo el primero porque lo uso para sumar los totales
  for (var a = arreglo[i].length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
    resultado[a].aceptacion += arreglo[i][a].aceptacion
    resultado[a].rechazo += arreglo[i][a].rechazo
  }
}

console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una respuesta bastante mas compleja pero muy eficiente y con muy buena performance.

```js
let arreglo = [
    [{
        aceptacion: 1,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 1
      }
    ],
    [{
        aceptacion: 2,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 7
      }
    ],
    [{
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 2
      },
      {
        aceptacion: 0,
        rechazo: 3
      }
    ]
 ];
 
const suma = (arreglo) => 
 arreglo.reduce(( acc, arr ) =>
  acc.concat(arr.reduce((acc, { aceptacion, rechazo } ) => {
   acc.aceptacion += aceptacion;
   acc.rechazo += rechazo;
   return acc;
  }, {aceptacion: 0, rechazo: 0})
 , []));
  
  console.log(suma(arreglo));
```